# Unable to insert data in mysql database with php 'ERROR!'

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know where I'm doing wrong. The task is not completing. I have huge content and wanna insert the data in database.

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxxx";
    $db_name = "xxxxxx";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error){
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $conn->set_charset('utf8');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO lyrics_a (title, content, category) VALUES 
(
[
'xxxxx',
'xxxxxxx<br>xxxxxxxxx<br>xxxxxx',
'xxxxxxxxx'
]
[
'xxxxx',
'xxxxxxx<br>xxxxxxxxx<br>xxxxxx',
'xxxxxxxxx'
]
[
'xxxxx',
'xxxxxxx<br>xxxxxxxxx<br>xxxxxx',
'xxxxxxxxx'
]
)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Error message :

```
Error: INSERT INTO lyrics_a ('title', 'content', 'category') VALUES ([' xxx','xxx','xxxx' ])
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''title', 'content', 'category') VALUES ([' xxx,'xxx','xxxx' ])' at line 1
```

I'm newbie. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a single quote.

```
INSERT INTO lyrics_a ('title', 'content', 'category') VALUES (['xxx->HERE<-,'xxx','xxxx' ])
```

You cannot insert 3 values at the same time, try to do it separately.
You may also want to use [preg-quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on your values.

Answer (score 0):

A missing `'` in your Values and a unneeded  `'` in the column name `'content`

Instead of this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO lyrics_a (title, 'content, category) VALUES 
(
[
'xxxxx',
'xxxxxxx<br>xxxxxxxxx<br>xxxxxx',
'xxxxxxxxx'
]
[
'xxxxx',
'xxxxxxx<br>xxxxxxxxx<br>xxxxxx',
'xxxxxxxxx'
]
[
'xxxxx',
'xxxxxxx<br>xxxxxxxxx<br>xxxxxx',
'xxxxxxxxx'
]
)";
```

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO lyrics_a (title, content, category) VALUES ('xx','xxx','xxxx')";
```

> Note: If `xx`, `xxx`, `xxxx`are strings, use proper wrapping like in the example below.

```
$xx = "";
$xxx = "";
$xxxx = "";
$sql = "INSERT INTO lyrics_a (title, content, category) VALUES ('$xx','$xxx','$xxxx')";
```